# How to count the ones in a binary representation of a given hex in a cmd Batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, binary, hex, counting

i am trying to write a batch file that asks the user to type a hexadcimal number and then counts the number of ones in the binary representation , like if i typed A the program echos 1 .

i have this code that uses a look up table to convert from binary to hex and answered by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) here ...

```
    @echo off
setlocal

set "bin=110111101010110110111110111011111100101011111110"
call :bin2hex hex=%bin%
echo hex: %hex%
goto :EOF

:bin2hex hexVar=binValue
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (0000-0;0001-1;0010-2;0011-3;0100-4;0101-5;0110-6;0111-7;1000-8;1001-9;1010-A;1011-B;1100-C;1101-D;1110-E;1111-F) do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%b in ("%%a") do (
      set "hextable[%%b]=%%c"
   )
)

set "hex="
set "bin=000%~2"
:bin2hexloop
   set "hex=!hextable[%bin:~-4%]!%hex%"
   set "bin=%bin:~0,-4%"
if defined bin if "%bin:~3%" neq "" goto bin2hexloop
endlocal & set "%~1=%hex%"
goto :EOF
```

i tried to inverse the way this code works , but it didn't work !

here is my attempt

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "hex=ABCDEF"
call :hex2bin bin=%bin%
echo : %bin%
pause;
goto :EOF


:hex2bin binVar=hexValue
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (0-0000;1-0001;2-0010;3-0011;4-0100;5-0101;6-0110;7-0111;8-1000;9-1001;A-1010;B-1011;C-1100;D-1101;E-1110;F-1111) do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%b in ("%%a") do (
      set "bintable[%%b]=%%c"
   )
)

set "bin="
set "hex=000%~16"
:hex2binloop
   set "bin=!bintable[%hex:~-4%]!%bin%"
   set "hex=%hex:~0,-4%"
if defined hex if "%hex:~3%" neq "" goto hex2binloop
endlocal & set "%~4=%bin%"
goto :EOF
```

anybody can help me ?

Comment: It seems to me that you were just guessing... anyway, upon a quick view, I think that: 1. `set "hex=000%~16"` should read `set "hex=%~2"`; 2. `set "bin=!bintable[%hex:~-4%]!%bin%"` should read `set "bin=!bintable[%hex:~-1%]!%bin%"`; 3. `set "hex=%hex:~0,4%"` should read `set "hex=%hex:~0,1%"`; 4. the `if defined` line should be `if defined hex goto hex2binloop`; 5. the `endlocal` line should be `endlocal & set "%~1=%bin%"`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want *not* to "convert a hexadecimal number to binary", but to "count the ones that each hex digit have" and accumulate they (for example, for A the number is 1). This way, the solution must work with "The number of ones each hex digit have".

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "hex=ABCDEF"
call :countOnesInHex ones=%hex%
echo There are %ones% ones in %hex%
pause
goto :EOF


:countOnesInHex ones=hexValue
setlocal

for %%a in (0-0;1-1;2-1;3-2;4-1;5-2;6-2;7-3;8-1;9-2;A-2;B-3;C-2;D-3;E-3;F-4) do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%b in ("%%a") do (
      set "onesIn[%%b]=%%c"
   )
)

set ones=0
set "hex=%~2"
:hexCountLoop
   set /A ones+=onesIn[%hex:~0,1%]
   set "hex=%hex:~1%"
if defined hex goto hexCountLoop
endlocal & set "%1=%ones%"
exit /B
```

Comment: thats really a brilliant idea and yes you got me :) thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Convert the number to decimal and do the basic math: divide by 2 and sum the remainders.

Do it in chunks of 7 hexadecimal digits because batch file calculations support only 31 bits (2^31-1 or 2147483647 or 0x7FFFFFFF).

```
set hex=ABCDEFABCDEFABCDEF

set ones=0
:loopchunks
    set /a decimal=0x%hex:~0,7%
    set hex=%hex:~7%
    :loopdigits
        set /a ones+=decimal %% 2, decimal/=2
        if not %decimal%==0 goto loopdigits
    if defined hex goto loopchunks

echo %ones%
```

Output:

> 51

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR %%a IN (F37ABD abcdef 123 321 99 100 f11f 0 cafe) DO CALL :mainproc %%a

GOTO :eof

:mainproc
SET hexnum=%1

SET /a count1=0
:loop
SET /a hex1=0x%hexnum:~0,1%
:bitloop
SET /a count1+=%hex1% %% 2
SET /a hex1/=2
IF %hex1% gtr 0 GOTO bitloop
SET hexnum=%hexnum:~1%
IF DEFINED hexnum GOTO loop
ECHO %count1% 1s detected IN %1
GOTO :EOF
```

The `for` loop simply assigns the values in the list to the variable `%%a` in turn and executes the main part of the procedure with a parameter (`%1`) of that item.

Within the main procedure, initialise `hexnum` as the number to be analysed and `count1` with the accumulated number of `1`s

Then set `hex1` to `0x`strung before (copy the first digit of `hexnum`) which will be a hex numeric, `0x0` to `0xf`. SInce this is the format for `cmd` to accept a hex number, it sets `hex1` to decimal 0..15

next add (`hex1` mod 2) to `count`, that is 1 or zero if odd/even

next halve `hex1`. Since `cmd` calculates in integer mode, the result is truncated, hence 6=>3 and 7+>3

the result is >0, do the next binary digit. repeat until 0.

Toss out the first character of `hexnum` (assign the substring starting at character 1, given that it starts counting at "character 0")

If `hexnum` has characters left, repeat for the next hex digit

otherwise, report.

result:

> 17 1s detected IN F37ABD
>   17 1s detected IN abcdef
>   4 1s detected IN 123
>   4 1s detected IN 321
>   4 1s detected IN 99
>   1 1s detected IN 100
>   10 1s detected IN f11f
>   0 1s detected IN 0
>   11 1s detected IN cafe